# about javascript arrow function expression

Tags: javascript

I am Korean, so I hope you could understand it with my awkward English skills

I am studying arrow function expressions

and here is my question with source code

```js
var arguments = [1, 2, 3];
var arr = () => arguments[0];

console.log(
  arr()
)


function foo(n){
  var f = () => arguments[0] + n
  console.log(arguments[0]) //5
  console.log("----arguments[0]")
  return f();
}
console.log(
  foo(5)
)

console.log("---------------------")

function fooo(n){
  var f = (...arguments) => arguments[0] + n
  console.log(...arguments) //5
  console.log("----...arguments")
  return f(2);
}

console.log(
  fooo(5)
)
```

I don't get why the second function's console.log = 10 and third function's = 7
can anyone explain to me the order code process and why that output is?
thank you.

Comment: `arguments` in `f` in the second one refers to the arguments of `foo` ... arguments in `f` the third one refers arguments to `f` ... first one clearly returns 5 + 5, third is 5 + 2

Answer (score 2):

In JS, every conventional function has a built-in object called `arguments`. However,  Arrow functions do not have this built-in object. So, if referred to `arguments` from within an Arrow function, the reference automatically goes to any external variable declared by that name.

The result you see is due to this effect. In regular function calls. your reference to the `arguments` global variable actually refers to their in-built `arguments` object.

The following code demonstrates this effect.

```js
let arguments = 'this is a string';

function argumentsTest() {
   console.log(arguments);
}


let argumentsArrowTest = () => {
   console.log(arguments);
}


argumentsTest(10);        //{0: 10}
argumentsArrowTest(10);   // this is a string
```

Comment: thank you a lot for replying my question!

Answer (score 0):

In an arrow function, `arguments`, like `this`, will refer to either

- an outer identifier named `arguments` (though it's very unusual to call a variable `arguments` due to name collision), or
- the arguments provided to a full-fledged `function`

whichever is closer, lexically.

In `foo`,

```
var f = () => arguments[0] + n
```

is an arrow function, so `arguments` refers to an outer binding. The outer environment is

```
function foo(n){
  var f = () => arguments[0] + n
```

so `arguments` refers to the arguments provided to `foo`. Here, it's similar to doing

```
function foo(n){
  const theArguments = [n];
  var f = () => theArguments[0] + n
```

And since the argument passed to `foo` is 5, that plus `n` (the same argument) is 10.

In the third function, the same logic applies. Inside an arrow function, `arguments` refers to the closest identifier named `arguments`, or the closest function. Here, it's the parameters:

```
var f = (...arguments) => arguments[0] + n
```

Since `f` is called with a single argument, this simplifies to

```
var f = (arg) => arg + n
```

That argument is 2, and the `n` is what's passed to `fooo`, which is 5. Add them together, you get 7.